Visual Studio Code doesn't activate my virtual environment
Visual Studio code does not activate my virtual environment on creation of a new terminal window, even though it is selected and the setting is activated. I am on wsl2 with python 3.10.12.
If I open a new terminal I expect a prompt with the current environment activated i.e. (.env) user@pc:/cwd$


Did you already use Select Python Environment with the command palette? (Ctrl+Shift+P by default)
What happens if you do which python after that? Sometimes you actually have the environment activated, it just doesn't show as (.env) in the terminal


Yes, the environment is selected. Omg actually which python shows the correct one, you're right just the terminal prompt prefix is missing. What a waste of time, thank you!

As I said in the comment, for some reason, sometimes the name of the virtual environment doesn't show up in the terminal like (.env). But it is still activated.
If you go to the command palette (Ctrl+Shift+P by default) and search for Python Select Interpreter, you should be able to choose your virtual environment.
The binaries you will see might depend on the version of Visual Studio Code you are running. For example, I was running the Windows version with WSL and I couldn't find my binary, because VSCode was looking for a python.exe file. But if I created the venv with Git Bash, it creates the binary for Windows.
The important thing you need to check for is if which python returns the correct path to your python binary from your virtual env.

If somebody knows the reason why this happens, it would be a good complement to this answer ;)
EDIT: There is an issue related to this here. Thx kyrlon for the info! =)
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/23008

maybe this is helpful: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/23008
